# Excel Visual Basic Copy Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

My objective is to create a piece of code that will create a copy of a template sheet for each string in an array - renaming the copied sheet to match the string.

This is the first time I have used Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications. I have added my code under "ThisWorkbook". However when I run the code I get a

> Subscript out of range

error.

```
    Sub generateStationTabs()
        Dim stringNames() As Variant
        Dim currentString As String
        Dim previousSheet As String

        previousSheet = "Template                 "

        stringNames() = Array("String 1", "String 2", "String 3", "String 4", "String 5", "String 6", "String 7", "String 8", "String 9", "String 10", "String 11", "String 12", "String 13", "String 14", "String 15", "String 16", "String 17", "String 18", "String 19", "String 20", "String 21", "String 22", "String 23", "String 24", "String 25", "String 26", "String 27", "String 28", "String 29", "String 30")
        For indexVariable = 0 To UBound(stringNames)
            ' Pad String Name to 20 Characters Length       currentString = Left(stringNames(indexVariable) & Space(8), 20)
            ' Copy the Template worksheet to after the Previous Sheet
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Template                 ").Copy after:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(previousSheet)         
            ' Rename the copied worksheet
            ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = currentString         
            ' Update the previous sheet
            previousSheet = currentString
        Next

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not yet defined `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(previousSheet)` so it can't find it. Essentially, you are asking Excel to look for a sheet it hasn't created yet, and thus can't find.

Instead you could try...

`ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Template                 ").Copy after:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)`

...and then rename the sheet as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

The code would be like this.

```
Sub generateStationTabs()
    Dim stringNames() As Variant
    Dim currentString As String
    Dim previousSheet As String

    previousSheet = "Template"

    stringNames() = Array("String 1", "String 2", "String 3", "String 4", "String 5", "String 6", "String 7", "String 8", "String 9", "String 10", "String 11", "String 12", "String 13", "String 14", "String 15", "String 16", "String 17", "String 18", "String 19", "String 20", "String 21", "String 22", "String 23", "String 24", "String 25", "String 26", "String 27", "String 28", "String 29", "String 30")
    For i = 0 To UBound(stringNames)
        ' Pad String Name to 20 Characters Length       currentString = Left(stringNames(indexVariable) & Space(8), 20)
        ' Copy the Template worksheet to after the Previous Sheet
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Copy after:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ' Rename the copied worksheet
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = stringNames(i)
        ' Update the previous sheet
        'previousSheet = currentString
    Next

End Sub
```